# Error when trying to loop through FormArray

Tags: angular

This is how I define my form:

```js
constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

formMain = this.fb.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required],
  description: ['', Validators.required],
  currency: ['USD'],
  items: new FormArray([]),
});
```

I would like to loop through `items`.

```html
<form [formGroup]="formMain">
  <button (click)="addField()">Add Fields</button>
  <div formArrayName="items">
    <ng-container *ngFor="let item of formMain.get('items')?.controls">
      <input type="text" [formControl]="item" value="foo">
    </ng-container>
  </div>
</form>
```

Well, when I try this, I get the error

> Property 'controls' does not exist on type 'AbstractControl'.

How can I fix this? I am using Angular 13.3.0.

Comment: try `formMain.get('items')['controls']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Angular definition for `formMain.get('items')` is as below. It does not know what actual type (`FormControl` or `FormArray` or `FormGroup`) is.

```
get(path: Array<string | number> | string): AbstractControl | null;
```

You have to define a method that return type is assumed as `FormArray`.

```
getItems = (): FormArray => {
  return this.formMain.get('items') as FormArray;
}
```

Then your template will be like this.

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let item of getItems().controls">
```